# I want to count the attribute of an xml file in Powrshell

Tags: xml, powershell

This is my XML file content wherein I want to count attributes ***such as name, failures, skipped***

As an output, I'd like something like:

```
> Total name = 2, 
>Total failures =1, 
>Total Skipped =0,
>Total passed = 1
>
```

In my xml file attribute failures = 0 resembles pass and 1 as fail

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="TVIA_Gold" tests="2" failures="0" skipped="0" time="48.5294792" timestamp="2022-05-27T10:28:20" id="3a03e3e7-7cb8-da92-8a08-b369c6fd15af" log="">
        <testcase name="Gold Price Option" time="63789244138.9715" timestamp="" log="+ Passed Gold Price Option&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Close all instace of Edge Browser {LogInfo='Started 'taskkill' with arguments '/f /im msedge.exe''}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  TBox Wait {LogInfo='Waited for &gt;5000&lt; milliseconds.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Open Application&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Navigate to Enter Vehicle Data page for Automobile&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Automobile {LogInfo='WaitOn was successful.&#xD;&#xA;Expected value: &quot;== True&quot;&#xD;&#xA;Actual value: &quot;True&quot;',UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Automobile {UsedValue='X'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Screenshot Navigate to Enter Vehicle Data page for Automobile {LogInfo='The screenshot was successfully created.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Enter Vehicle Data and Click on Next&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Make {LogInfo='WaitOn was successful.&#xD;&#xA;Expected value: &quot;== True&quot;&#xD;&#xA;Actual value: &quot;True&quot;',UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Make {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Engine Performance [kW] {UsedValue='150'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Date of Manufacture (MM/DD/YYYY) {UsedValue='05/17/2018'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Number of Seats {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Fuel Type {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   List Price [$] {UsedValue='10000'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Annual Mileage [mi] {UsedValue='10000'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Next {UsedValue='X'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Screenshot Enter Vehicle Data and Click on Next {LogInfo='The screenshot was successfully created.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Enter Insurant Data and Click on Next&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   First Name {LogInfo='WaitOn was successful.&#xD;&#xA;Expected value: &quot;== True&quot;&#xD;&#xA;Actual value: &quot;True&quot;',UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   First Name {UsedValue='Shawn'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Last Name {UsedValue='Frost'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Date of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY) {UsedValue='05/27/1992'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Gender {UsedValue='x'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Street Address {UsedValue='First  Avenue'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Country {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Zip Code {UsedValue='20011'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   City {UsedValue='New York'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Occupation {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Other {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Next Â» {UsedValue='X'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Screenshot Enter Insurant Data and Click on Next {LogInfo='The screenshot was successfully created.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Enter Product Data and Click Next&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Start Date (MM/DD/YYYY) {LogInfo='WaitOn was successful.&#xD;&#xA;Expected value: &quot;== True&quot;&#xD;&#xA;Actual value: &quot;True&quot;',UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Start Date (MM/DD/YYYY) {UsedValue='07/07/2022'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Insurance Sum {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Merit Rating {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Damage Insurance {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Legal Defence Insurance {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Courtesy Car {UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   Next {UsedValue='X'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Screenshot Enter Product Data and Click Next {LogInfo='The screenshot was successfully created.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Select Price Option and Click Next&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   priceTable {LogInfo='WaitOn was successful.&#xD;&#xA;Expected value: &quot;== True&quot;&#xD;&#xA;Actual value: &quot;True&quot;',UsedValue='True'}&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed   View Quote {UsedValue='X'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Screenshot Select Price Option and Click Next {LogInfo='The screenshot was successfully created.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Close Edge Browser {LogInfo='Started 'taskkill' with arguments '/f /im msedge.exe''}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" />
        <testcase name="Print PDF Report" time="63789244141.0105" timestamp="" log="+ Passed Print PDF Report&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Print PDF Report {LogInfo='Started 'C:\Tosca_Projects\TCShell\Execution.bat' with arguments '&quot;/6_UsersInTraining/Arkamauli Ghosh/Import_import220517_1115/Test_Env_TestCase/DEX_Execution_TestCase/Component/Dex_Execution/TVIA_Gold/TVIA_Gold&quot; TVIA_Gold SETF\DealerPortal''}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" />
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="TVIA_Silver" tests="2" failures="1" skipped="0" time="35.8853641" timestamp="2022-05-27T10:27:12" id="3a03e3e7-7cb9-2606-517a-6a00b34ca528" log="">
        <testcase name="Silver Price Option" time="63789244060.9361" timestamp="" log="  Error Silver Price Option&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Close all instace of Edge Browser {LogInfo='Started 'taskkill' with arguments '/f /im msedge.exe''}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  TBox Wait {LogInfo='Waited for &gt;5000&lt; milliseconds.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Open Application&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;  Error  Navigate to Enter Vehicle Data page for Automobile {LogInfo='&#xD;&#xA;Version 20.0.0.13 of the Edge Addon has been detected. Please install version 21.x.x.x of the Addon for your Edge.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Screenshot Navigate to Enter Vehicle Data page for Automobile {LogInfo='The screenshot was successfully created.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;  Error  Enter Vehicle Data and Click on Next {LogInfo='&#xD;&#xA;Version 20.0.0.13 of the Edge Addon has been detected. Please install version 21.x.x.x of the Addon for your Edge.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Screenshot Enter Vehicle Data and Click on Next {LogInfo='The screenshot was successfully created.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;  Error  Enter Insurant Data and Click on Next {LogInfo='&#xD;&#xA;Version 20.0.0.13 of the Edge Addon has been detected. Please install version 21.x.x.x of the Addon for your Edge.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Screenshot Enter Insurant Data and Click on Next {LogInfo='The screenshot was successfully created.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;  Error  Enter Product Data and Click Next {LogInfo='&#xD;&#xA;Version 20.0.0.13 of the Edge Addon has been detected. Please install version 21.x.x.x of the Addon for your Edge.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Screenshot Enter Product Data and Click Next {LogInfo='The screenshot was successfully created.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;  Error  Select Price Option and Click Next {LogInfo='&#xD;&#xA;Version 20.0.0.13 of the Edge Addon has been detected. Please install version 21.x.x.x of the Addon for your Edge.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Screenshot Select Price Option and Click Next {LogInfo='The screenshot was successfully created.'}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Close Edge Browser {LogInfo='Started 'taskkill' with arguments '/f /im msedge.exe''}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;">
            <failure message="Test failure">  Error Silver Price Option</failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="Print PDF Report" time="63789244062.6585" timestamp="" log="+ Passed Print PDF Report&#xD;&#xA;+ Passed  Print PDF Report {LogInfo='Started 'C:\Tosca_Projects\TCShell\Execution.bat' with arguments '&quot;/6_UsersInTraining/Arkamauli Ghosh/Import_import220517_1115/Test_Env_TestCase/DEX_Execution_TestCase/Component/Dex_Execution/TVIA_Silver/TVIA_Silver&quot; TVIA_Silver SET\VehiclePortal''}&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" />
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I am stuck as i am not getting attribute as an Object to store the value as an **int** and then add to count as an output i think I am lagging a bit with PowerShell as I am very much new to it and below is my small code which I used to get the XML file to parse

```
$paths = "C:\imp\TestReport.xml"
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path $paths
$XmlDocument.GetType().FullName
#$XmlDocument.testsuites.testsuite | Format-Table -AutoSize | 

$info = $XmlDocument.testsuites.testsuite | Format-Table -AutoSize

#Write-Output $info
```

Comment: You want one set of output _per test suite_, or for the entire thing/overall?

Comment: Use XPath to filter by attribute value? `SelectNodes("//*[@failures='0']")`

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is like

```
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$xml.Load('C:\imp\TestReport.xml')
$result = [PsCustomObject]@{
    'Total TestSuites' = $xml.testsuites.testsuite.Count
    'Total Failures'   = (([int[]]$xml.testsuites.testsuite.failures | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    'Total Skipped'    = (([int[]]$xml.testsuites.testsuite.skipped | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    'Total Passed'     = $totalTestSuites - $totalFailures
}

$result | Format-List
```

Using your example XML this would output

```
Total TestSuites : 2
Total Failures   : 1
Total Skipped    : 0
Total Passed     : 1
```